# Where does my DDD logic belong?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, tdd, domain-driven-design

I’ve been persuaded by Eric Evans’ book and am integrating DDD into my framework. All basic elements (services, repositories, bounded contexts, etc) have been implemented and now I’m looking for feedback on how to correctly integrate this.

I have some business logic which has to be performed when an entity is created or modified. This example is a very simple one. Most business logic will become much more complex.

This business logic can be split up into the following actions:

1. Update calculated fields;
2. Update a child record inside the aggregate root. When creating the aggregate root this entails creating a default child record. When updating the aggregate root this entails removing the existing child record and creating a new one if a specific field on the aggregate root has changed;
3. Propagate start and end date of the aggregate root to the start and end date of the child records inside the aggregate root. These must be kept in sync under certain circumstances;
4. Propagate a field of the aggregate root to a different aggregate root.

My first attempt is to put all of this on the aggregate root, but I feel this is not going to work. I have the following problems integrating this logic:

- All these actions have to be completed as a single whole and should not be made available as separate actions. This has the result that this is going to be very difficult to test (TDD);
- I am not clear on whether any of these actions can be moved out to a service. The reason for this is that they make no sense outside of the aggregate root, but it would make TDD a lot easier;
- Some logic changes depending on whether a new entity is created or an existing one is modified. Should I put these two branches inside the update logic or should I make two entirely different paths that share the business code that does not differentiate based create/modify.

Any help on the above issues would be greatly appreciated and other feedback in general.

Comment: Do you really have to propagate values to the children?  i.e. can't you just use getX() methods on the children that read the value from the parent? e.g. Child.getX() {return parent.getX();}.  Might even save you from having to replace the children.  Just a  thought.

Comment: Legacy application. What you're gonne do :).

Comment: In DDD the word Service direct rings alarm bells, as it so often is a way to ignore OO concept like encapsulation and is just a euphemism for plain old procedural code.

Comment: @Kdeveloper - Your answer makes me very curious because the DDD book specifically describes services. Could you explain a little bit more how you see services work in context of DDD? What you think their purpose should be and how that compares to the wrong usage you describe?

Comment: wrt @Kdeveloper's comment on services.  DDD does indeed talk about Services.  The risk is that all the business logic ends up in services, leaving the objects solely as data containers (the "anaemic data model @orangepips mentions below).  So the DDD advice is basically: first, ask which object any domain behaviour belongs in.  If it *really* doesn't belong in a single object, then - and only then - put it in a domain service.

Comment: @sfinnie @Kdeveloper - All my properties are private so I forced myself to move as much logic into the entities itself. The question then becomes what of the described logic could be placed in a service, and why? Btw, this is the feedback I'm looking for. Don't hesitate to create an answer so I can vote on it :).

Comment: Also I like to cite Evans DDD, Chapter on Services (Page 104): "There are important domain operations that can't find a natural home in an entity or value object. Some of these are intrinsically activities or actions, not things, but since our modeling paradigm is objects, we try to fit them in objects anyway. Now, THE MORE COMMON MISTAKE IS TO GIVE UP TO EASILY on fitting the behavior into an appropriate object, gradually slipping toward procedural programming."

Comment: @Pieter, I was about to create an answer, but I noticed that orangepips already created one I agree with.

Comment: For anyone following along, I recommend reviewing InfoQ's Domain Driven Design Quickly (http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) if you're unfamiliar with DDD - this is what the Evan's book should be IMO. As far as Service layer is concerned, it's about delegating to domain objects and convenient location for providing status to client code - think batch processes, reporting, or long running processes in background threads.

Comment: So you're saying: fit it all into the entity unless it's really entity agnostic and has no business in an entity? And this at least goes for the examples I gave, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, entity specific behavior should be housed inside of it.

Comment: Pretty much agree with all above.  Only final comment is to be wary of how you think about the term "service layer".  There's a danger of visualising it as a layer somehow 'above' or providing access to the domain entities/values.  That in turn can foster the misconception that other layers (e.g. Application Layer) can only call Services, not call operations on Domain Entities/Values directly.  That's not right - and can lead to the anaemic domain model.  It's better to think of the "Domain Layer" as consisting of Domain Entities, Values and Services all of which have equal status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm you've described should remain in the aggregate root, elsewise you end up with an [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), excepting propagating a field to another aggregate root where I will describe what I think you should do later.

As far as TDD is concerned, a method with "package" access on the aggregate root (e.g. "calculate()", should coordinate the entire action, which either the service or repository object would normally call. This is what tests should exercise in conjunction with setting different combinations of instance variables. The aggregate root should expose its instance variables, the children collection, and each child should expose its instance variables, through getters - this allows tests to validate their state. In all cases if you need to hide information make these getters package or private access and use your unit testing framework to make them public for the purpose of testing.

For your testing environment consider [mocking](http://www.mockobjects.com/) the repository objects (you're using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) right?) to return hard coded values. Short of this consider using something like [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to work with a database in a known state.

As far as logic changes are concerned create vs. modify, are you referring to how to persist or is there an actual algorithm to consider? If the former, I would make the repository responsible, if the latter I would make two separate methods (e.g. "calculateCreate()" & "calculateUpdate()") which calculate() would delegate as appropriate.

Also, there's a concurrency issue to think about as well because it sounds as if calculated values rely on mutable fields. So either need to have careful locking or aggregate roots that can only be used by a client once at a time. This also applies to propagating a field across aggregates - I would probably use the repository for this purpose - but you need to think carefully on how this should or should not impact other clients who are using the repository object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First, yes I'm using Castle Windsor and Rhino. Further, so you're saying that I should make the separate methods available at package level for TDD?

Comment: Yes. Make package access methods that a unit test can call directly by having the unit testing package make the method public for the purpose of the test. For your application, these method(s) are called implicitly - so code using aggregateRoot wouldn't be able to call calculate() directly because it's not public. So instead  service.save(aggregateRoot) - or repository.save(aggregateRoot) - calls aggregateRoot.calculate() internally.

Comment: And concerning the create/update logic. The method that decides which business logic methods are to be called should differentiate based on create/update mode, not the business logic itself?

Comment: In terms of persistence, if possible I would use the same path for create and update e.g. "service.save()". Inside the service, I would do what you can most easily unit test. From what you've written I think you can check for the existence of the aggregateRoot and update or insert as appropriate. For the children, it sounds as if they are dependent on the parent for their existence, in which case the easiest path may always be to delete and then insert. Granted if there are a lot of children this may prove to be too inefficient, but it's definitely the most straightforward.

Comment: I'm using CQRS so the entity itself decides what business logic to execute; very neat idea. I think I understand the idea. Thanks very much for your help.